# Why I can't take 10 character input with scanf? each time I enter a character the loop iterates twice. Why?

Tags: c

I want to take character input using scanf instead of getchar(). So I wrote this coder but each time I input one character value it iterates twice. So I am able to take only 5 inputs. Why is this happening?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    char arr[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d:", i);
        scanf("%c", & arr[i]);
        printf("%c", arr[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to consume the trailing newline left by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key when `%c` is used as format specifier in `scanf`, otherwise the `\n` remains in the buffer being consumed as an input/character in the next iteration.

Switch from

```
scanf("%c", & arr[i]);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &arr[i]); // Notice a space before %c
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. But can you kindly explain why its happening?

Comment: If you typed “abcdefghij” and then hit return, @RifatAlEmamShoron, then you would see what you wanted.  When you type “a” and return, you type two characters which are read in succession.